# GUI2Exe build with smtplib [Have windows gui interface

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, smtplib, gui2exe

My problem is similar to this post:

["No module named email.utils" in smtplib with gui2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284352/no-module-named-email-utils-in-smtplib-with-gui2exe/41156994?noredirect=1#comment69516036_41156994)

but it comes along with a GUI
I did not used any email.py in all of my module

The program processes all information and broadcast it through email in a schedule..
But it also needs a GUI to prompt information to a certain user that is are the information being broadcast

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "mainwindow.pyc", line 17, in <module>
  File "mysendMail.pyc", line 2, in <module>
  File "smtplib.pyc", line 46, in <module>
ImportError: No module named email.utils
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solve this problem.

I just added the smtplib and email python modules upon creation of the executable application
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNEgy.png)